# laravel Eloquent relationship using Distinct

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, group-by, relationship, distinct

I need show data with relationship using DISTINCT.

This is my sql data :

**table pochettes**

```
id | 
49 |
```

**table journees**

```
id | formateurs_id | pochettes_id
1  | 3             | 49
2  | 4             | 49
3  | 3             | 49
```

**table formateurs**

```
id | 
3  |
4  |
```

***model Pochette***

```
public function Journees()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Journee','pochettes_id');
}
```

***model Journee***

```
public function Formateurs()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Formateur', 'formateurs_id');
}
```

I am used this code to show data with distinct formateurs because a Formateur can have many Journee in the same Pochette :

```
$pochette = Pochette::find(49);
foreach ($pochette->Journees->distinct('formateurs_id') as $formateur) {
            echo $formateur->formateurs_id;
            echo "<br>";
        }
```

But this code dosn't work, I have this error message

```
    **BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81:
Method distinct does not exist.**
```

I would show this result :

```
3
4
```

not :

```
3
4
3
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you access an Eloquent relationship like a property, you will get an [Eloquent Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections). However, `distinct()` is a [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries) method and you need access to the Query Builder instance before returning the Collection. If you add `()` to the end of the relationship, you gain access to the Query Builder instance and can chain those Query Builder methods. In your case, you are actually looking for the `groupBy()` method and not `distinct()`. Don't forget to end the query with `get()`.

```
foreach ($pochette->Journees()->groupBy('formateurs_id')->get() as $formateur) {
    echo $formateur->id ;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: @Ayedmedamine  Then you are looking for `groupBy()` and not `distinct()`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Add () to access query builder was something I never knew. Don't think its even there in the docs?